# Convert jQuery .html to vanilla js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am converting a project away from jQuery and I thought this would be trivial...How do I convert:

```
let tb = $("#design_table tbody");
tb.html("");
```

I tried:

```
let tb = document.querySelector("#design_table tbody");
tb.innerHTML = "";
```

When I use the above my table becomes:

```
[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]...etc
```

There is only 1 table with tbody tag

Edit:
The querySelector appears to be selecting the table:

```
<tbody>
  <tr title="row_0">
    <td title="col_0" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_1" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_2" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_3" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_4" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
...etc.
```

This works, but still half jQuery:

```
let tb = $("#design_table tbody");
tb.innerHTML;
```

**Code**:

```
function reDraw () {
      let tb = $("#design_table tbody");
      tb.html("");
      for (var y = 0; y < MCD.settings.fieldHeight; y += 1) {
        var new_row = $("<tr>", {
          title: "row_" + y
        });
        for (var x = 0; x < MCD.settings.fieldWidth; x += 1) {
          let new_cell = $("<td>", {
            title: "col_" + x,
            //class: "material_" + MCD.matrix[y][x] + " rotate_0",
            class: "material_" + MCD.matrix[y][x][0] + " rotate_" + MCD.matrix[y][x][1],
          });
    new_row.append(new_cell);
        }
        tb.append(new_row);
      }
  }
```

**Update**:
For:

```
let tb = $("#design_table tbody");
      console.log(tb)
      tb.html("");
      let ab = document.querySelectorAll("#design_table tbody");
      console.log(ab[0]);
```

Console.log returns:

```
d { 0: HTMLTableSectionElement, length: 1, prevObject: d, context: HTMLDocument, selector: "#design_table tbody" }
<tbody>
  <tr title="row_0">
    <td title="col_0" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_1" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_2" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_3" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_4" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_5" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_6" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_7" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_8" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_9" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_10" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_11" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_12" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_13" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_14" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_15" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_16" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_17" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_18" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
    <td title="col_19" class="material_0 rotate_0"></td>
  </tr>
...etc...
</tbody>
```

Obviously two different results, but I don't understand why.

Comment: And in what way does the code not work as expected?  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: You cannot use the ID selector in the manner you are ..  You need to use `document.querySelectorAll("#design_table tbody, #tbody");` Or if you just want to change `tbody` ..  Leave design_table out ..  `document.querySelector("#tbody");`

Comment: @Zak: *"You cannot use the ID selector in the manner you are"* - [Sure you can](https://jsfiddle.net/z650nyqL/).  Of course whether or not it finds the target element depends on the HTML, which neither of us can see right now.  But there's no reason to assume here that `tbody` is meant to be an `id` and not an element.

Comment: You aren't showing the `table` element that contains the `tbody` element in your example above. Need to confirm the table has the right `id`. Otherwise it looks like the replacement code should work. does your replacement code find the right element, or does it end up null?

Comment: @dqhendricks when I console.log the table prints out correctly. It looks like it should work

Comment: @maddogandnoriko: [Your code works.](https://jsfiddle.net/6pk4y09t/)  There's nothing in the code shown which would produce "[object Object]" as output.  And the "works, but still half jQuery" version doesn't do anything at all.  Please provide a [mcve] which actually demonstrates a problem of some kind.

Comment: `let tb = $("#design_table tbody");
      tb.innerHTML = "";` makes no sense if it is jQuery. jQuery does not have innerHTML. so you are just creating a property od innerHTML on the jQuery object collection. So you are NOT resetting the html of the tbody.

Comment: @maddogandnoriko: Regarding the update... *"Obviously two different results, but I don't understand why."* - Because one is a jQuery object and the other is an HTML element.  They're two very different things with very different functionality.  In your block labeled "**Code:**" the reason it "doesn't work" is because the jQuery object has no `innerHTML` property.  You're dynamically creating that property and setting it to an empty string, but there's no reason to expect anything to ever use that new property you just created.

Comment: I fixed the ***Code*** section.  It was an error, apologies.

Comment: @David Are my first two code blocks direct replacements for each other?

Comment: @maddogandnoriko: Functionally those two code blocks accomplish the same task, yes.  And have already been demonstrated to work as expected.  Though the rest of your question strays from that considerably...

Comment: @Thank you. I did not realize jQuery created a different type of result. I believed it just did the same thing as js, only simpler syntax. I believe there is code downwind of that that is using  the jquery result.

Comment: Agreed got off subject...thanks again. You did solve my issue, it was just a different issue than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly, it translates like this:

```js
function reDraw () {
  //let tb = $("#design_table tbody");
  let tb = document.querySelector('#design_table tbody');

  //tb.html('');
  tb.innerHTML = '';

  for (var y = 0; y < MCD.settings.fieldHeight; y += 1) {

    //var new_row = $("<tr>", {
    //  title: "row_" + y
    //});
    var new_row = document.createElement('tr');
    new_row.title = 'row_' + y;

    for (var x = 0; x < MCD.settings.fieldWidth; x += 1) {

      //let new_cell = $("<td>", {
      //  title: "col_" + x,
      //  class: "material_" + MCD.matrix[y][x][0] + " rotate_" + MCD.matrix[y][x][1],
      //});
      let new_cell = document.createElement('td');
      new_cell.title = 'col_' + x;
      new_cell.className = 'material_' + MCD.matrix[y][x][0] + ' rotate_' + MCD.matrix[y][x][1];

      new_row.append(new_cell);
    }
    tb.append(new_row);
  }
}
```

This isn't an exact translation. For example, jQuery creates wrappers for the elements and passes those around.

After clean up and optimizing, it looks like this:

```js
function reDraw () {
  const html = [];

  for (var y = 0; y < MCD.settings.fieldHeight; y += 1) {
    html.append(`<tr title="row_${y}">`);

    for (var x = 0; x < MCD.settings.fieldWidth; x += 1) {
      html.append(`<td title="col_${x}" class="material_${MCD.matrix[y][x][0]} rotate_${MCD.matrix[y][x][1]}"></td>`);
    }

    html.append('</tr>');
  }

  const tb = document.querySelector('#design_table tbody');
  tb.innerHTML = html.join('');
}
```

Comment: I was trying to do javascript stuff with a jQuery variable.